# SQL Server 2008 R2 installed, still cannot open version 661?

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

Getting an error running a sample MVC2 site because of DB version errors. I ran the installer for SQL Server Express 2008 R2 and it finished, I rebooted. Try to run the site again and see the same error. Downloaded/ran R2 installer and chose upgrade but there is nothing to upgrade... is something wrong in my VS2010 or windows in general? Don't know what else to do.

Just ran a discovery report and 2008 is also installed. Maybe thats the problem?

```
Product Instance    Instance ID Feature Language    Edition Version Clustered
Sql Server 2008 SQLEXPRESS  MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS  Database Engine Services    1033    Express Edition 10.1.2531.0 No
Sql Server 2008 SQLEXPRESS  MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS  SQL Server Replication  1033    Express Edition 10.1.2531.0 No
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2    MSSQLSERVER MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER  Database Engine Services    1033    Express Edition 10.50.1600.1    No
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2    MSSQLSERVER MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER  SQL Server Replication  1033    Express Edition 10.50.1600.1    No
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2            Management Tools - Basic    1033    Express Edition 10.50.1600.1    No
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two installions. Had two instance names. Changed the instance name in VS2010 database tools.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to connect VS 2010 to the SQL server database in this instance C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS. Also ensure in SQL configuration manager, SQL browser and SQL instances are running and set to automatic and Network service
Seems to me it will be able to connect to SQL express database instances only when logged in as administrator VS 2010 express editions to create/modify an application.